# Move Upload file is not working on windows server?

Tags: php, windows

I have some problem to upload the file from php into the  windows live server not Linux. `move uploaded file`  same i use the `copy` inseted of move uploaded file but this is not working.

**This whole code is fine working on the local machine** when i set this code in live then give me the warning and not upload the any file in folder...

**Give me some help**

Here is my whole code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);  

        //$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
        $uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/img/customer_image/";
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['customer_image']['name']);

    echo "<p>";

    if ( (copy($_FILES['customer_image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))) {
      echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
       echo "Upload failed";
    }

    echo "</p>";
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";
```

[image]

Comment: why don't you use move_uploaded_file()

Comment: @MahaDev I am using this bt don't work then  i am using the copy

Comment: give all permission to folder **customer_image**

Comment: @Rahautos where to set the all permission  to ** customer_image ** folder in winows server??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$dir= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/img/customer_image/";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['customer_image']['tmp_name'], $dir. $_FILES["customer_image"]['name'])) {
    echo "Uploaded";
} else {
   echo "File was not uploaded";
}
```

**Set permission for folder in windows**

> 1.Right click the folder and click properties
>
> 2.click security tab
>
> 3.select Group or username and click edit button

[image]

> 4.Check  permissions if any one is marked Deny ,then uncheck it
>
> 5.click Apply OK

Comment: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /webcorp1/www/corpusers/j/o/johnsautomation.in/admin/add_customer.php on line 21 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpwaT005' to '/webcorp1/www/corpusers/j/o/johnsautomation.in/img/customer_image/Awards.jpg' **in this error show me**

Comment: i read this but where to change the all permission i am setting the permission like this  **rwxr-xr-x** in the customer_image folder

Comment: This is code working fine in my local machine but when i set the my webpage in live server then this have been problem for me.....???

Comment: it should be the file permission problem, and I have no experience with that. However look my edited answer. If `Deny write access` I can't write to the file.